# Axios Request Interceptor wait until ajax call finishes

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I have an request interceptor for axios calls. It checks my jwt token and call for refresh if necessary.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) =>{

    const state = store.getState(); // get renewed state
    const time = Math.floor( new Date().getTime() / 1000 );

    if( 
        ! state.app.jwtRefreshOnRequest 
        && time >= state.jwt.expires - 120
        && state.jwt.refresh_before > time
    ){ // expiring in 2 min. refresh    

        //dispatch({type: 'JWT_REFRESH_REQUEST'});
        axios.get( API_BASE_URL + '/auth/refresh')
            .then(function(response){
                // dispatch({type: 'JWT_REFRESH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data});
                axios(config).then(resolve, reject);
            })
            .catch(function(err){               
                reject(err);
        });

    }       

    return config;
});
```

This code calls the refresh correctly and saves the new token but the original call doesn't holds until the interceptor request is done, so the expired token is used.

So, I guess I need to make synchronous call from interceptor.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Avoid synchronous calls for HTTP requests, as they just make your application hang.

What you need to do here is make the calling code asynchronous - the general rule with anything callback, promise or async related is that once you are async everything needs to be async.

Here, `axios.get` returns a `Promise` - an object that keeps track of the asynchronous HTTP request and resolves once it has finished. You need to return that, rather than the `config`.

We do that by returning a new `Promise` - if an HTTP request for a new token is required it waits for it, if no it can `resolve` immediately.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ... your code ...

        axios.get( API_BASE_URL + '/auth/refresh')
            .then(response => {
                // Get your config from the response
                const newConfig = getConfigFromResponse(response);

                // Resolve the promise
                resolve(newConfig);
            }, reject);

        // Or when you don't need an HTTP request just resolve
        resolve(config);
    })
});
```

Whenever you see that `then` you're dealing with `Promise`, and once you are *everything* needs to return a `Promise`.

This is *much* easier if you can use `async`/`await` - new keywords supported by modern browsers and transpilable if you need to support legacy users. With these you can just put the `Promise` call inline with the `await` keyword.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async config =>

    // ... your code ...

    if(/* We need to get the async token */) {
        const response = await axios.get( API_BASE_URL + '/auth/refresh');
        config = getConfigFromResponse(response);
    }

    return config;
});
```

Comment: its not clear what getConfigFromResponse(response)  does??

Comment: @ace It turns the `response` object into the `config` format - it wasn't part of the problem so the implementation is up to you. It could be `await response.json()` assuming that the status is ok and you add an outer `await`. In this answer it's just a placeholder.