# How to add interceptor function to Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Alright, So I'd like to add a response interceptor to my global axios config, that **retries** a request **once** if it gets a 401 error, after refreshing the token.

This is my current global axios config:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  responseType: "json"
});
```

Now I've did research my issue has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646853/automating-access-token-refreshing-via-interceptors-in-axios), however, I'm not aware how I can attach or use the interceptor function in the answer there to my axios config file (after I edit it to my needs ofc) the interceptor function looks like this:

```
createAxiosResponseInterceptor() {
    const interceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
        response => response,
        error => {
            // Reject promise if usual error
            if (errorResponse.status !== 401) {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }

            /* 
             * When response code is 401, try to refresh the token.
             * Eject the interceptor so it doesn't loop in case
             * token refresh causes the 401 response
             */
            axios.interceptors.response.eject(interceptor);

            return axios.post('/api/refresh_token', {
                'refresh_token': this._getToken('refresh_token')
            }).then(response => {
                saveToken();
                error.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token;
                return axios(error.response.config);
            }).catch(error => {
                destroyToken();
                this.router.push('/login');
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }).finally(createAxiosResponseInterceptor);
        }
    );
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need to invoke the interceptor creator function on your custom axioms instance. So something like:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  responseType: "json"
});

function createAxiosResponseInterceptor(axiosInstance) {
    const interceptor = axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
        response => response,
        error => {
            // Reject promise if usual error
            if (errorResponse.status !== 401) {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }

            /*
             * When response code is 401, try to refresh the token.
             * Eject the interceptor so it doesn't loop in case
             * token refresh causes the 401 response
             */
            axiosInstance.interceptors.response.eject(interceptor);

            return axiosInstance.post('/api/refresh_token', {
                'refresh_token': this._getToken('refresh_token')
            }).then(response => {
                saveToken();
                error.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token;
                return axiosInstance(error.response.config);
            }).catch(error => {
                destroyToken();
                this.router.push('/login');
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }).finally(createAxiosResponseInterceptor);
        }
    );
}

createAxiosResponseInterceptor(instance);

export default instance;
```

And make the `createAxiosResponseInterceptor` function take the axios instance as a parameter.

Comment: Alright that sounds good but where do I place the function to begin with? Somewhere else and import?

Comment: I guess it shouldn't really matter. If you don't need it anywhere else (probably not), I'd put it in the same module...

Comment: It seems that the placement of the function is still improper, any clues? prntscr.com/ptqim8

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call your intercept creator with custom instance of axios.
You can do it as

```
const instance = axios.create({
 baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
 headers: {
 "content-type": "application/json"
 },
 responseType: "json"
});
```

and pass this instance to createAxiosResponseInterceptor as

```
createAxiosResponseInterceptor(instance);
```

You would have to change your createAxiosResponseInterceptor to receive this instance as

```
function createAxiosResponseInterceptor(instance) {
const interceptor = instance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
        // Reject promise if usual error
        if (errorResponse.status !== 401) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        /* 
         * When response code is 401, try to refresh the token.
         * Eject the interceptor so it doesn't loop in case
         * token refresh causes the 401 response
         */
        instance.interceptors.response.eject(interceptor);

        return instance.post('/api/refresh_token', {
            'refresh_token': this._getToken('refresh_token')
        }).then(response => {
            saveToken();
            error.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token;
            return instance(error.response.config);
        }).catch(error => {
            destroyToken();
            this.router.push('/login');
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }).finally(createAxiosResponseInterceptor);
    }
);
}
```

and of course export as

```
export default instance;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Very helpful, but it seems that the placement of the function is still improper, any clues?
http://prntscr.com/ptqim8

Comment: you need to use function keyword